# Object method mocking or spying for unit testing in Scala

Tags: scala, mocking, scalatest, spy

Is there a way to mock or spy on methods in a Scala object?

```
object Object {

  def fun(value: String) = println(value)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    fun("executed")
    sys.exit(0)
  }
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
spy(Object.fun)
```

I looked at `ScalaMock`, `EasyMock`, `JMock` and `Mockito` but couldn't really figure it out.

Comment: You can't mock an object. More importantly, you really, really, really shouldn't need to. Everything, that needs mocking should be its own separate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be not to use a Scala object for this. It isn't testable.

Like in java you should avoid using Static as it can't be relaced with a mock.

If you want to have one instance of the class you can instatiate it once in an `object`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally split the logic of my main in few more testable methods